# rebinding RMI port in java docker container

Tags: java, docker, rmi

I have simple java application running a RMI registry on port 3456, It is only a registry during the startup it does not exposes any service. Instead I have a client which basically gets the registry and bind the service on the fly. However I am getting error

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.bind disallowed; origin /172.17.0.1 is non-local host
```

Below is the main class

```
public class RMIMock {

    public static void main(String... args) throws RemoteException {

        SpringApplication.run(RMIMock.class, args);

        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(3456); // this line of code automatic creates a new RMI-Registry. Existing one can be also reused.

    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# we will use openjdk 8 with alpine as it is a very small linux distro
FROM container-registry.ubs.net/openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.8

# copy the packaged jar file into our docker image
COPY target/xcoll-virtualization-rmi-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /demo.jar

# set the startup command to execute the jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/demo.jar"]
```

command to run image

```
docker run -p 3456:3456 -it xcoll-virtualization-rmi-service:1.0
```

Client:

```
LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 3456).bind("testDao", new RmiMockImpl());

        RMIDao rmiDao = (RMIDao) Naming.lookup("rmi://10.203.178.10:1200/testDao");
        System.out.println(rmiDao.getAllForDate(new Date()));
```

Comment: Do you need to run the client on the host? What happens if the client is also in a container?

Comment: I may want to try adding `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` to the server's CMD

Comment: @OneCricketeer client will run on the host which is basically a test case also adding localhost does not makes any difference

Comment: Well, the port is connecting. The error is about remapping the server's bind address to allow non-local connections

Comment: You can't bind to a non-local registry. That's what the error message says and it is also what the documentation says. Rethink your design.